# Python: Email addresses

Tags: python, email

**Python 3**

`# -- coding: utf-8 --
email = input ( 'Email: ' )
print email # oÓ.öŐ §'"+!%/=()@uÚ.üŰ §'"+!%/=().com`

I would like:

`print email # oo.oo@uu.uu.com`

- Latin 1 (**ISO-8859-1**) characters, at sign (**@**) and dot (**.**).
- Lowletters.
- The (white) *space* and *special characters* are delete.

Sorry, I speak a little English.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Why do you hate international domain names?

Comment: Also, you miss a **lot** of characters valid in an email address.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be accomplished with the `string.translate()` function.

See: [Python Docs - String](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate).

See also: [This tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm).